# my issue is that i insert multiple image in one row with comma separated in codeginter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am so tried to insert to multiple images its work perfectly but    what i want to multiple images insert in to database with one row    means comma separated like that for example `id =4` and `img =    img1,img2,img3,img4` i want insert in one row in codeginter but don't    know how to use this function `$data= implode(",",$userfile);` THANKS    advances brother

**Here is my controller function**

```
function blog_img_new()
{
    $imgtest = $this->blog->image_get_test();
    $this->template->load_sub('imgtest', $imgtest);
    $this->template->load('admin/test-imag');
}

function blog_img()
{
    $number_of_file = sizeof($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    $file = $_FILES['userfile'];

    // Faking upload calls to $_FILE
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_file; $i++) :

        $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $file ['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $file ['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $file ['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $file ['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $file ['size'][$i];

        $config['upload_path'] = './photo/uploads'; //The path where the image will be save
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

        $data = $this->upload->data();

        $file_name[] = $this->upload->data();

        $data = array(
            'userfile'   => $this->upload->data('file_name'),
        );

        $data= implode(",",$userfile);
        $this->blog->blog_img($data);

            //redirect('/admin/blog/img/insert');
    endfor;

}
```

**this is my model function**

```
function blog_img($data)
{
    $userfile = addslashes($data['userfile']);
    return $this->db->query("INSERT INTO filename_img (userfile) VALUES ('$userfile')");
}
```

**view page**

```
<input type="file"  name="userfile[]" id="userfile" multiple >
```

Comment: You shouldn't store multiple values as a comma separated string in one column like that. You should [read about Database Normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) instead.

Comment: brother it should be possible @Akshay Parate because i create the separate table for the images

Comment: first of all - you insert within your for loop - which means you insert any value one by one and second of all where is your corresponding id value ? You mention it in your question but you dont have one in your model nor in your controller ....

Comment: i give just example for the id @sintakonte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the insert function out of the loop. In the loop you have to assign each filename to an array you can implode.

```
    function blog_img()
    {
        $number_of_file = sizeof($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
        $file = $_FILES['userfile'];

        $files = array();

        // Faking upload calls to $_FILE
        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_file; $i++) :

            $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $file ['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $file ['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $file ['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $file ['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $file ['size'][$i];

            $config['upload_path'] = './photo/uploads'; //The path where the image will be save
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

            //$data = $this->upload->data();

            $files[] = $this->upload->data('file_name');

            //$data= implode(",",$userfile);
            //$this->blog->blog_img($data);

                //redirect('/admin/blog/img/insert');
        endfor;

        $data= implode(",",$files);
        $this->blog->blog_img($data);
}
```

Model using QB:

```
function blog_img($files)
{
    $this->db->set('userfile', $files);
    return $this->db->insert('filename_img');
}
```

Comment: brother i shwo this error Message: Illegal string offset 'userfile'

Filename: admin/Blog.php

Line Number: 247 and my query is error in function blog_img($data){
   
   $userfile = addslashes($data['userfile']);
   

   return $this->db->query("INSERT INTO filename_img (userfile) VALUES ('$userfile')");
@alex

Comment: Use my model function, it works differently than yours

Comment: oooo brother thank you so much bundle of thanks brother 
but brother i have one query how it work eidt update and delete and it is possible i get only one images in front end

Comment: Explode to get images as an array from db then you can select one, and update delete is the same method as this, but you will have to explode remove the one you want to delete or update then implode and save. Serializing your string and saving to the db isn't preffered for database columns as someone in the comments suggested. Please mark answer as accepted.

Comment: brother how i use Explode function in<img src="<?php echo base_url()."photo/uploads/".$images->userfile ?>" style ="width: 100px;">  in these line any help brother @alex

Comment: `explode(',',$images->userfile)[0]` // for first image